# Typing related record keys and values in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I have some types that look like this, where I have a common field `type`, but then each subtype has different attributes:

```
type Cat = { type: 'Cat', likesMilk: boolean }
type Dog = { type: 'Dog', barksLoudly: boolean }

// ...many more

type Animal = Cat | Dog | ...
```

I would like to end up with an object which maps animal types to a function taking an animal as a parameter, something like this:

```
map['Cat'] => (animal: Cat) => void
map['Dog'] => (animal: Dog) => void
```

My first approach is `Record<Animal['type'], (definition: Animal) => void`. However, this does not prevent me from doing something like `map['Cat'] => (animal: Dog) => void`.

A working approach, but problematic, is this:

```
interface AnimalMap {
  Cat: (cat: Cat) => void;
  Dog: (dog: Dog) => void;
  // ...
}
```

However, this is a pain to maintain as it means that there are multiple places to update whenever adding a new animal - and if I forget to add the animals to the typing, I don't get any compilation error. Meanwhile, having a `Record<Animal['type'], ...>` means that if I add a new animal subtype and forget to update the map, TS is going to throw a compilation error, which is the desired behavior.

So the challenge is to ensure that an animal type maps to a function accepting only that kind of animal, but to define that in a way which is going to keep working as new animals are added. What I'm looking for is something like `T extends Animal` and then `Record<T['type'], (animal: T) => void>`, but I don't know how this can be achieved using TS.

Answer (score 1):

A TypeScript wizard at work has given me the solution:

```
type AnimalMap = {
    [A in Animal as A['type']]: (animal: A) => void
}
```

This ensures that this doesn't work as I get a compilation error:

```
export const obj: AnimalMap = {
    Cat: (d: Dog) => console.log(d), // type mismatch!
    Dog: (d: Dog) => console.log(d),
}
```

and also that if I modify the `Animal` definition to `Cat | Dog | Lizard`, I get a compilation error because I need to modify `AnimalMap` to include a function for `Lizard`. So that ticks all the boxes!